# Overlap of picture box with the user control

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i have overlapping problem in windows form application.

I have many images overlapping one over the another. So i am unable to view the controls that is placed last.

I also set the visibility of the other controls to false. still i am unable to view the last control Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to call Refresh on the parent(s) whenever you show or hide a control. The Winforms faked transparency workaround makes control with transparent parts copy their parents and maybe some of those pixels stay after your showing/hiding..

Comment: @TaW Hi, i fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set transparent as a back color to all the controls. and then aligned. then i got this issue fixed